# How to remove custom logo in Dailymotion using api?

Tags: dailymotion-api

How to remove custom logo in Dailymotion using api?

Example : https://dailymotion.com/video/xxxxx?autoplay=1&-----

Answer (score 0):

If by `custom logo` you mean the watermark on the bottom right of the player, this is only manageable from your channel settings on your partner space [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/partner/embed/player-customization)